# Google Analytics filters, only two countries

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want create a filter for include only two countries. For example United Kingdom and Russia.

I have two filters, first is excluding all countries. It is a filter where I set regex as pattern `'.'` and next filter is including only for this countries, pattern: `United Kingdom|Russia`.

But now I don't have any results displayed. Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Why are you excluding all countries in your filter? If you do that, then you would get no data. You should only need the include filter. Can you please also attach a screenshot of your filters?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine. You need to include the variable against which the regex filter is going to be executed. In your case, type `Country` (`Pays` in French)

Preview (Sorry for the French):

[image]

PS: I have tested it on my G account.

**Edit:**

As per your comment below, the `.` would only match one character (There are no countries with one character name). If you want to match all countries then your regex pattern would like `.+` yet that leaves with this question: If you want to match all countries why use a filter in the first place?

Comment: yes, i have it.. a have custom filter where i set exclude, type = Country and pattern = . but still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you set a filter to exclude all countries then there will be nothing in your reports, it does not matter what any other filters do because they cannot cancel each other out.

You simply need to place the include filter as it works as an "Include-only".

The RegEx you have already seems to be working on both filters, once again the problem is that your exclude filter is excluding everything.